# Unable to connect to RDS instance using MySQL client

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sequelpro

First thing first, I have checked almost all the answers related to this but couldn't find the cure to the problem.

To connect to RDS, I know that we need to set the inbound rules in the security group associated with the RDS instance to my machine's IP, which is already set.

Am just using a `mysql` client like `sequel pro`, specify the RDS endpoint, mention the username and pwd but everytime the connection could not be established.

There is no firewall as I am using my mobile internet by connecting my machine through hotspot.

One important thing that might be causing the issue could be the subnets that are associated with the default `VPC` on my `RDS`. I have 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets associated.

Also ran the command `nc rds-host port`, even that also timed-out.

Tried all troubleshooting steps but still not able to connect. Could somebody throw some light here. Stuck for a very long time.

This is the error:

```
Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'abcdef.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)
```

Comment: did you try to connect over local network?

Comment: No. Am on corp network currently and that has firewall for 3306.

Comment: I mean with in same VPC?

Comment: No. Don't really know how to do that?

Comment: try with connect form ec2 instance

Comment: With ec2 within same vpc, i am able to connect. But the requirement that I have is to connect this RDS with Tableau desktop that is installed on my machine and I need to create dashboards out of it.

Comment: Make sure security group allows the connection and make sure it not in private subnet and RDS enabled public access